# Setup a mocked EF Service method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have the following method in my NewsDataService class

```
public IEnumerable<NewsModel> GetImportantNews()
{
    var result = this.newsfeedRepository.GetAll(
        x => x.IsImportant == true,
        x => new NewsModel()
        {
            Creator = x.User.UserName,
            AvatarPictureUrl = x.User.AvatarPictureUrl,
            Content = x.Content,
            CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn);

    return result;
}
```

My question is...
How do I setup the mocked service method (`GetImportantNews`), 
so that it returns a list of `NewsModel` which are "Important"?

My idea is something like this, but it is not working so far, because it is always returning the full list.

```
var expectedResult = new List<Newsfeed>()
{
    new Newsfeed()
    {
       IsImportant = false,
    },
    new Newsfeed()
    {
        IsImportant = true
    }
};
mockedNewsfeedRepository
    .Setup(x => x.GetAll(
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Newsfeed, bool>>>(),
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Newsfeed, NewsModel>>>()
    )).Returns(expectedResult);
```

Basically what I want is my "expectedResult" to be filtered by the logic in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to the invocation arguments when returning a value. Apply the predicate and projection expression arguments to the fake data source using linq like in the example below.

```
mockedNewsfeedRepository
    .Setup(x => x.GetAll(
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Newsfeed, bool>>>(),
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Newsfeed, NewsModel>>>()
    ))
    // access invocation arguments when returning a value
    .Returns((Expression<Func<Newsfeed, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Newsfeed, NewsModel>> projection) =>
         expectedResult.Where(predicate.Compile()).Select(projection.Compile())
    );
```

Source: [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)